# Yii2 custom default router for more case

Tags: yii2

I only see solution set default router on web config. So how can i custome default router for more case.

Example: If user not login, will set site/index default router. And if user login, will set article/index for default router.

I reference toptic and see create class url, so i not clear.

Note, two router is publish, all member can access

Answer (score 0):

As you set default route in  `web/config` as `site/index` for all user and you want to different route for logged in user.

In site/index you can check that user is logged in or not and if user is logged in you can navigate it to particular route.

Example :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) { // redirect user to artical /index if user is logged in
        return $this->redirect(['article/index']);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check first if logged in

```
     if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $this->goHome();
    }else{
       return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]); }
```